# The server downloads source code insted of excuting code

Tags: node.js, express

I am using node.js with everyime i try to gon on localhost:8080 which is the port i am listening to , it downloads source code instead of showing web site.

I am executing app with

```
node name.js
```

it started doing out of sudden , what could be the source of this unwanted behavior?

Comment: What server are you using?

Comment: I am using express

Comment: Then we are going to need some more details, "it doesn't work" doesn't help us help you identify the actual problem here.

Comment: the problem is i do not know how to identify is , i have simple app , invoking it with node name.js command in CMD , it started downloading source instaed of excuting it out of sudden , without any changes made

Comment: Please add a [minimal, verifiable and complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of code that causes your problem to your question, then.

Comment: We need to see your actual server code to see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

make shure you are not using header "Content-Disposition"

try to see the respond headers (f12+ network tab)